# A regex to detect periodic strings

Tags: regex

> A period `p` of a string `w` is any positive integer `p` such that `w[i]=w[i+p]`
>   whenever both sides of this equation are defined. Let `per(w)` denote
>   the size of the smallest period of `w` . We say that a string `w` is
>   periodic iff `per(w) <= |w|/2`.

So informally a periodic string is just a string that is made up from a prefix repeated at least twice.  The only complication is that at the end of the string we don't require a full copy of the prefix.

For, example consider the string `x = abcab`. `per(abcab) = 3` as `x[1] = x[1+3] = a`, `x[2]=x[2+3] = b` and there is no smaller period. The string `abcab` is therefore not periodic.  However, the string `ababa` is periodic as `per(ababa) = 2`.

As more examples, `abcabca`, `ababababa` and `abcabcabc` are also periodic.

> Is there a regex to determine if a string is periodic or not?

I don't really mind which flavor of regex but if it makes a difference, anything that Python `re` supports.

Comment: which language you are using??

Comment: @Kilanny It's a general regex question but if it makes a difference, anything that Python re supports.

Comment: @ClasG How about horcrux's answer below?

Comment: @eleanora I think ClasG is referring to a pure regular expression. Pure regular expressions has the same expressive power of a regular grammar, and they cannot determine periods or impose cardinalities (see my answer below).

Comment: @horcrux yes you are right. I was always told that regex != regexp :)

Comment: @ClasG you are right about pure regular expressions and you are right that abcdae is not periodic.

Comment: @ClasG abcdaefga is not periodic. To have period 4 you would need a = a, b = e, c = f and so on.

Comment: @ClasG Yes abcabcabc is periodic. Why do you ask about that string?

Comment: Because with `\b((\w)\w+)\1\2\b` it [does not work](https://regex101.com/r/oJ3kJ0/1).

Comment: @horcrux oh dear!  Sorry I will add it as an example now.

Comment: @eleanora no fear, mine does work.

Comment: @horcrux Phew :) I added a more advanced follow up for the brave just now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326458/a-regex-for-maximal-periodic-substrings .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is backreference

```
\b(\w*)(\w+\1)\2+\b
```

This matches even `abcabca` and `ababababa`.

`\1` and `\2` are used to match the first and second capturing groups, respectively.

Comment: This looks very nice! I am just playing with it.

Comment: I think that if you consider periodic the empty string too, the right expression is: `\b(\w*)(\w*\1)\2+\b`

Comment: Very nice. Shorter than mine, but maybe a bit harder to grasp. IMHO you should use `^...$` instead of `\b...\b` to ensure that the entire string is periodic.

Comment: This is really nice. It even handles sequences *cut* in the beginning, like `cdabcdabcdabcd`. Thumbs up

Answer (score 4):

You could use Regex back references.

For example `(.+)\1+`. This pattern will match a group `()` formed of at least one character `.+`. This group `\1` (back reference) must repeat at least one time for a match.

The string `ababa` matches and it finds `ab` as the 1st group.

The string `abcab` is not a match.

**Later edit**

If you want a prefix that is repeated at least twice, you can change the pattern to: `^(.+)\1+`. The problem is that I don't think you can match the end of the string to a substring of the prefix. So any string that starts with a repeating pattern will match but it will ignore the ending of the string.

**Even later edit**

Inspired from @tobias_k answer, here is how I would do it `^((.+)(?:.*))\1+\2?$`. It looks for a string that has a prefix (it looks for the longest prefix it can find) that repeats at least twice and the ending must be the starting part of the prefix.

The first capturing group from the match will be the prefix that is repeating.

https://regex101.com/r/jQ3yY1/2

If you want the shortest prefix that repeats, you can use this pattern `^((.+?)(?:.*?))\1+\2?$`.

Comment: How about `abcabca` for example?

Comment: It matches abc. You can play with it here: https://regex101.com/r/jQ3yY1/1

Comment: Thank you but I think something is wrong. If I try abcabcab is matches "abcabc" where it should match "abcabcab" (that is the whole thing).

Comment: It will match `isthisstuffperiodic?` :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regex like `^(.+)(.*)(\1\2)+\1?$`.

- `^...$` from start to end of string
- `(.+)` part of period that is always repeated (e.g. `a` in `ababa`)
- `(.*)` optional part of period that is repeated except at the end (e.g. `b` in `ababa`)
- `(\1\2)+` one or more repetitions of the entire period
- `\1?` optional final repetition of first part of the period

In Python:

```
>>> p = r"^(.+)(.*)(\1\2)+\1?$"
>>> re.match(p, "abcab")
None
>>> re.match(p, "abcabca")
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x7f5fde6e51f8>
```

Note that this does not match the empty string `""` though, which could also be considered periodic. If the empty string should be matched, you will have to treat it separately, e.g. by simply appending `|^$` at the end of the regex.

Comment: "group that is repeated but at the very not". What does "very not" mean?

Comment: @eleanora It means that I made a typo. Fixed.